# Align ggplot and base plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know this might be a duplicate, but I'm desperate.

I have generated a scatter plot using ggplot out of data that look like this:

```
SNP   Pvalue   POS
rs..  0.0023   3133333
rs..  0.0003   5000000

etc...
```

the code looks like this:

```
gg <- ggplot(snps) +                                                #dots
    geom_point(aes(x = nrow(snps), 
                   y = snps$POS, 
                   size = -log10(snps$Pvalue)),             
               color = 'black') +
    geom_text_repel(size = 3, # font size
                    aes(x = nrow(snps), 
                        y = snps$POS,
                        label = snps$SNP),
                    color = 'black',
                    point.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"),
                    segment.color = 'black') +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
    scale_size("-Log10(Pvalue)", range=c(1,13), breaks = c(5,10,15,25,30,40,50,80,100,120,150,250,1900))
```

And also using custom functions that use `plot`. I've generated a plot to show the genes that are on that specific chromosome area.

the input for the genes look like this:

```
GENE   START         END   
X      3000000       3000123
Y      3109090       3200000
etc...
```

the code for this look like this:

```
range <- length(genes.data)
offset <- range
gene.y.min <- offset
gene.y.max <- (offset/6)

gene.rows <- nrow(genes.data) * 2

min.pos <- min(genes.data$START)
max.pos <- max(genes.data$STOP)

image.type <- "pdf"
c <- runif(length(genes.data$START), min = 0, max = length(genes.data))
plot(c, genes.data$START, type = "n")
plot.genes(genes.data, min.pos, max.pos, gene.y.min, gene.y.max, gene.rows)
```

Basically remember the last 2 lines. For the the `base plot`. Both the individual plots work as intended, and I just want to merge them together. They are using the same `y-scale` but they have to be aligned.

I want the final output to look something like this

```
-------------------------------
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
|base |         ggplot         |
|plot |                        |
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
--------------------------------
```

Both plots use the same values for Y-axis. `20mb-30mb`. So I need the information to be aligned

Comment: The `gridBase` package allows combinations of grid and base graphics. I haven't used it, but [this Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf) might be of help. As another option, If you provide sample data (paste the output of `dput(data_sample)` into your question) and more information about what you're trying to do, we may be able to help you create a ggplot version of your base plot.

Comment: @eipi10 if you know that the code i provided for the 2 plots works fine individually. is it no possible to merge them>?

Comment: `grid` graphics and base graphics are generally incompatible. The `gridBase` package provides methods to create some compatibility between the two different graphics systems. I don't know of another way, besides `gridBase`, to combine `grid` and base graphics within R.